# Where is f(x) differentiable?

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

[image]

The graph above is f(x).

I initially thought that it would be differentiable for all values of x between -2 and 4 since it seems to be defined for all those values. However, that answer was wrong.

Any help?

Comment: Are you sure that it does not behave as a Weierstrass function when you zoom the graph?

Comment: This is the only picture I was provided with.

Comment: In general, she cannot be differentiable where she is discontinous. How would you draw the tangent at points where she is not continuous? I know, that was a joke with Weierstrass function.

Comment: I was thinking that it would be differentiable in certain intervals. Not necessarily throughout.

Comment: Differentiability implies continuity, so discontinuity implies non-differentiability.

Comment: What did you learn about a concept of differentiability by now?

Comment: There is a huge problem at x=1

Comment: @AntoinedePaladin That you take the tangent at a point and find its gradient. I did not know that the graph had to be continuous.

Comment: First get rid of the discontinuities which are at $x=-1, 0,1$. Next get rid of points where graph seems to have a corner. You should be able to write your answer now.

Comment: @sktsasus Yes it must. Because how would you take the tangent where she is not continuous.

Comment: @sktsasus The tangent, when she exists, approximates very well the curve at a point where she is drawn from both sides of that point when you do not go too far from that point. But if graph is disconnected then at the point of discontinuity you cannot attain good approximation from both sides.

Comment: @AntoinedePaladin Yes I see. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @sktsasus No problem, it is my duty to help

Answer (score 1):

Differentiable is not equivalent to defined for all values. The real definition of differentiable is that the derivative of the function exists at all points (on the interval). This means that since $f'(-1)$ is undefined ($\lim_{x\rightarrow -1^-}f'(x)$ is clearly much greater than $\lim_{x\rightarrow -1^+}f'(x))$, the function is not differentiable on the domain given.

Answer (score 1):

The function is differentiable when $$\lim_{x\to\ a^-} \frac{dy}{dx} = \lim_{x\to\ a^+} \frac{dy}{dx}$$ Unless the domain is restricted, and hence at the extremes of the domain the only way to test differentiability is by using a one-sided limit and evaluating to see if the limit produces a finite value.

Hence, the function described by the graph provided is differentiable on the interval $$x \in [-2,-1) \cup (-1,0) \cup (0,1) \cup (1,3) \cup (3,4]$$

Comment: Thank you for your, virtually, correct answer. I think I should tell you that the correct answer had a ( in front of the -2 in the first interval and not a [. In other words, the interval looked like this: (-2,-1). Regardless, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

To be differentials, a function must be continuous **and** have no sharp corners. (Endpoints of the function are considered sharp corners.)

Looking at the graph, the function is discontinuous at

- $x<-3$, because the function is not defined
- $x=-1$, because the point there is removed from the graph to either side
- $x=0$, because of an asymptote
- $x=1$, because the function jumps
- $x>4$, because the function is not defined

The function has sharp corners at

- $x=-2$, because the curve has an endpoint there
- $x=-1$, because the ‘slope’<sup>*</sup> coming in from the left is different than coming in from the right
- $x=3$, because the ‘slope’<sup>*</sup> coming in from the left is different than coming in from the right
- $x=4$, because the curve has an endpoint there

Everywhere else, the function is differentiable.

Remember—*differentiable* is a subcategory of *continuous*.

<sub>* i.e., of the tangent line</sub>

PS: You know a function is continuous if you can draw its graph without picking up your pencil.